# System of Equations: $3x + 5y = -4$, $x + 2y = -2$

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I'm having trouble understanding how to apply matrix to systems of equations.

Here's the problem I need help with. This must be solved using matrices.

$$3x + 5y = -4\\
x + 2y = -2$$

Comment: They way how you wrote it, is not really a system of equations, unless it is to be read as $3x+5y=-2$ and $-4x+2y=-2$

Comment: @imranfat I've tidied the formatting, OP had a single line in between the two equations which wasn't being displayed

Comment: Ah I see. Now it becomes easy :)

Comment: What methods do you know for matrices: Row reduction, inverses, Cramer's rule?

Answer (score 0):

So you have $$\left(\begin{matrix}3&5\\1&2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\implies\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}3&5\\1&2\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$=\left(\begin{matrix}2&-5\\-1&3\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$=\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$$